# Port knocking as poor (wo)man's approach to steer IOT devices?

Tags: linux, security, architecture, iot

First off, I am well aware that port-knocking does create more security-feeling than real saftey, and that it is mainly a security-by-obscurity thing. Nevertheless: **Are there are open-source projects around which use e.g. [knockd](https://linux.die.net/man/1/knockd)  as replacement for a full-fledge architecture to steer a simple IOT-device?**

#### More details on the setup

Let me elaborate a bit my idea: The IOT-device is a Raspberry (or any other single board computer) which performs a visible action (like opening or closing a window shutter). In other words, I do not need any feedback from the device via IP or UDP protocol. All I need is a demon of some kind listening for a handful of commands (for the window shutter this may be `open-completely`, `close completely`, `open further by a third if state allows`, `close further by a third if state allows`). The Raspberry is aware of the current state of the shutter, accepts a new command only once the last one is fully executed, and limits the number of commands per time interval. If my knocking-sequence is long-enough, I would reach a higher security than many IOT-devices on the market (remember the old joke: *"S" stands for security in IOT*).

While brain-storming the idea of my simple Raspberry-window-shutter-project, the old [CGI bin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) approach came into my mind, nowadays it would possibly be a [python http.server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) or something similar. Both these approaches seem a bit overkill to me. There are some ready-to-use mobile apps like [Knock on Ports](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.impa.knockonports) which I could immediately use to test my setup. But before I reinvent the wheel, I would love to know whether I have overseen some existing projects going in a similar direction.

#### Further reading

- Dave McKay: *[How to Use Port Knocking on Linux (and Why You Shouldn’t)](https://www.howtogeek.com/442733/how-to-use-port-knocking-on-linux-and-why-you-shouldnt/)*
- [Simple way to set up port knocking on Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/411443/simple-way-to-set-up-port-knocking-on-linux)

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. Isn't a [`knockd`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/knockd) all you need on the IOT device? You can configure different knocking sequences for the different window shutter actions, e.g. `sequence = 7000,8000,9000; command = python open_completely.py` . What is lacking in `knockd` for your use case?`

Comment: https://www.cipherdyne.org/fwknop/ / https://www.cipherdyne.org/blog/2015/06/new-android-single-packet-authorization-client-fwknop2.html / https://manpages.debian.org/fwknopd.8 / https://manpages.debian.org/fwknop.8 comes to mind for a secure approach, but you already linked it. So what's the problem with this one? The package would be available on RPi.